# What is this tool for?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

[image][image]

I bought the tool illustrated above for a project around the house, but I cannot remember what it is used for, or what project I used it on. Anyone have any ideas as to what this tool is for? I did quite a bit of internet searches, but could not come up with an image that might give me a clue. I do not believe it is a tool for tensioning tie wraps, but, it may be. There is no branding on the tool to indicate by whom it was manufactured. I believe it is for putting tension on something, but what I do not recall.

So, any ideas out there as to what this tool is for, or where it can be purchased? It is just making me nuts.

---

Comment: Wire stripper optimized for stranded wire? What does it do when you actuate it?

Comment: I figured it out. Sat here thinking about it all day, no, two days. Got it. It is a "Molly Bolt Expander." You can buy them on Amazon. They have been used in Europe (Germany) for over 35 years. Check out this YouTube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHF0Womke6k

Answer (score 4):

User 71827 is correct.  A wall anchor setting tool, or Molly Expander
[image]

Comment: That's... weird. Here I was thinking that driving the screw in is what expanded the molly in the wall. I'm almost afraid to ask how/why you would use this.

Comment: Driving the screw certainly does expand the molly if the tiny points don't spin in the drywall... the tool avoids that situation and very quickly expands the mollys with no risk of spinning them.  (in fairness, im too cheap, and ive never spent the $30 on one... but i have spun the mollys and had to come up with a way to hold them while I expanded them with a screwdriver)